# The radius of convergence of this function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

In class today we were given the power series

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^22^{3n-2}}(x-3)^{3n+1}$

and we have to find the radius of convergence

After running through all the working I get to

$|x-3|^3 < 8$

Does this mean that the radius of convergence is 8 or would it be $\sqrt[3]{8}$ I am just a little confused

Comment: The radius is $2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $2$ and then the given series converges for $|x-3|<2$, then we need to check directly the cases $x-3=\pm2 $, that is

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^{3n+1}}{n^22^{3n-2}},\quad \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(2)^{3n+1}}{n^22^{3n-2}}$$